# iOS looking for new shared files

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Where's the best place in an iOS application to look wether or not the user has added new files to the shared files from his app? In the awakeFromNib method? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The awakeFromNib: method is fine, but you can also do this in one of the initialization (-initWith...) methods, or when the application delegate is being instantiated by UIKit, in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method. Also make sure to check for new files in th e applicationDidBecomeActive: method, and you may also want to add a Refresh button or Pull-to-Refresh to your app for ergonomical reasons.